# Output of hints function from hints package in R

Tags: r, knitr, sweave, xtable

The following code has been taken from document of hints package. Last line of this code is throwing error.

```
library(hints)
m <- lm(BOD)
hints(m)
library(xtable)
xtable(hints(m))
```

The error is

```
Error in UseMethod("xtable") : 
  no applicable method for 'xtable' applied to an object of class "hints"
```

I wonder how to get `hints` function  output to use in `knitr` or `sweave` document with `xtable` function.

Comment: Thanks @Dason for your comment. Can you tell what are the other methods to display hints output in knitr? Remember hints output is not showing in R Console.

Comment: From `hints` function documentation: _The object is compatible with the xtable package to get LaTeX output, and all the arguments to xtable can be used._

Comment: I'm not sure the sweave or knitr tags are appropriate here since this problem doesn't really have anything to do with them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like xtable.hints is provided by the package but isn't properly exported so you can't actually use it.  It's a fairly simple function though and the easiest solution would probably be to just copy the source and make your own function that does the exact same thing.

```
xtable.hints <- function(x, align = "llll", ...){
    x <- as.data.frame(x$results[, c(2, 1, 3)])
    colnames(x) <- c("Package", "Function", "Task")
    xtable(x, align = align, ...)
}

x <- 1:10
y <- rnorm(10)
o <- lm(y~x)
xtable(hints(o)) # now it works
```

Comment: By the way I figured this out by looking at `library(help=hints)` and seeing that xtable.hints is a part of the package but then discovering that it wasn't exported.  You can still view the function with `getAnywhere(xtable.hints)` though so that's how I grabbed the source code for it.

Comment: I submitted an issue on the page for the hints package.  We'll see if Hadley fixes it or not.  It's a *really* easy fix but I doubt this package is at the top of his priority list right now.